# Hogwarts 'exceeds expectations' passing grade

Tags: harry-potter

Is the passing grade **'exceeds expectation'** measured in the degree of how well a student in a particular class has performed, or is it simply the idea of a student's performance in class literally exceeding the teacher's expectations?

In many of Harry's classes with Snape, before *Half-Blood Prince*, he has been looked down upon and treated roughly, to the extent where he has received **Dreadfuls** (D) and the **mark 0** from practical potions concocting and theoretical examinations. So why has Harry received Exceeds Expectations from Snape in the O.W.Ls?

Is it a caliber of excellence or an instance of a student merely exceeding a teacher's expectation in the literal sense?

Comment: it could be a bit of a cultural thing - when I was university in the UK we were told that a higher class degree would only be awarded to those who exceeded expectations (ie, demonstrated ability and/or knowledge beyond the basic class material)

Comment: In the US on the other hand, the grades "B" and "A" were supposed to mean "exceeds expectations" and "outstanding", with "C" being "average" and "D" being "passing, barely".  [Nowadays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grade_inflation#Grade_inflation_in_the_United_States) teachers hand out higher grades than they should be, so there isn't a parallel to "exceeds expectations" anymore - you're supposed to get "A"s...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I think that you're forgetting that O.W.L.s were administered and scored by the Ministry of Magic, not the Hogwarts professor.

As such, the definition must have some expected norm, as an unbiased Ministry official wouldn't have any personal expectations for any individual student.

Comment: ... unless they were expecting a corporeal Patronus from a particular student. Unbiased-like. :)

Comment: @DVK -- The Patronus was totally off the record :)) They just wanted to see Harry produce one for kicks. Hannah Abbott accidentally produced a flock of flamingos that filled the Great Hall ... that was ... Patronus-like, in that animals were involved ... ;)

Comment: The OWL system is almost certainly based on the old [GCE Ordinary Level](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_Level) system, post-1975, which was in place when Rowling herself was in school.

Answer (score 5):

There was a W.O.M.B.A.T. test on JKR's old website.

The test itself was based on a [variety of multiple choice questions](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Wizards'_Ordinary_Magic_and_Basic_Aptitude_Test) about the Potter books. At the end of the test you received a grade (ranging from T-Troll to O-Outstanding) based on your score, along with a certificate which you can see below.

[image]

Since the OWLs (etc) are externally-administered (by the Ministry of Magic), it's not that you've exceeded the expectations of *your tutor*, it's that you've exceeded the expectations of someone at your current educational level.

Answer (score 2):

This quote from Fred and George in the Order of the Phoenix seems to suggest that the E grade does not indicate that the student passed the expectations of their teachers:

> 'So top grade's "O" for "Outstanding",' she was saying, 'and then
>   there's "A" –' No, "E",' George corrected her [Hermione], '"E" for
>   "Exceeds Expectations". And I've always though Fred and I should've
>   got "E" in everything, because we exceeded expectations just by
>   turning up for the exams.' 
>   *(OP15)- hp-lexicon.org*

Although it might also suggest that The teachers had higher expectations of the boys than they purported to have of themselves.

Comment: That sounds more like typical F&G punning...